# Scikit Random forest pred_proba gives rounded off values

Tags: machine-learning, probability, random-forest, scikit-learn

I am using random forest in scikit learn for classification and for getting the class probabilities , I used pred_proba function. But strangely it outputs probabilities rounded to first decimal place

Like
[0.1,0.4,0.5,0.2]

Is it the default output? Is it possible to increase the decimal places?

Comment: try to increase trees from default parameter of n_estimators from 10 to 500

Answer (score 7):

The predicted probability produced by random forests are the votes, i.e. the proportion of trees who voted for class 1. If you had 5 trees, your values could only be multiples of 0.2.

On the other hand, if you have 1000 trees, the range of possible values for the probabilities will be the multiple of 0.001